# Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

While executing the below command directly over the terminal, its working fine:

```
comm -2 -3 <(sort FileOne.txt) <(sort FileTwo.txt) > myFile.txt
```

But while trying to execute it via **.sh** file, its giving error: `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
##this will return the unique lines from the first file.
comm -2 -3 <(sort FileOne.txt) <(sort FileTwo.txt) > myFile.txt
```

I run the script like this:

```
sh ./myfilename.sh
```

Please help me to solve it.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you run the script? I suspect you run it with `sh` and not `bash`.

Comment: Yeah you should just run it with `./scriptname`.

Comment: running it like -  sh myfilename.sh

Comment: If you're new to bash scripting, I highly recommend [this video series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLT98CRl2KxKGj-VKtApD8-zCqSaN2mD4w) to get you started. Enjoy!

Comment: Process substitution syntax i.e. `<(...)` works in `bash` but not in `sh`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If needed, make the script executable first by running:

```
chmod +x myfilename.sh
```

Then, run the script like this:

```
./myfilename.sh
```

Or run it explicitly with bash like this:

```
bash myfilename.sh
```

*(These first two commands are essentially the same, since you have the bash shebang `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of your script.)*

DO NOT run like this:

```
sh myfilename.sh
```

Because then you are running the script with Dash (`sh`) and not with Bash (since your script has Bash-specific syntax).

Comment: +1 ... It might be worth noting that `chmod +x` is safer(*ish*) as it respects your environment's set `umask`(*file mode creation mask*) ... `chmod a+x` on the other hand should only be used if you **mean it** as it will set the executable bit for all(*owner, group and others*) regardless of the `umask` value.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is similar to answer already posted, but giving an explanantion.

I thing you are running this script `sh code.sh`. This means you are using `sh` to run the script, but the first line (`#!/bin/bash`) implies it's been written for `bash`.

On some systems `sh` and `bash` are the same, but on others they are not; and, when invoked as `sh`, `Bash` turns off some non-POSIX features. So it's important to use the right shell and the right invocation.

Use `bash code.sh` or better still, make the script executable (`chmod a+x code.sh`) and then run it directly (`./code.sh`)